# Existential types and pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

I'm trying to do something roughly like the following:

```
trait MyData

trait MyId

trait MyDataType[T <: MyData] {
   type MyIdType <: MyId

   // There can be converters here to bring back
   // lost type information.
}

trait Writer[T <: MyData] {
   def save(data: Map[T#MyIdType, T])
}

val writers: Map[MyDataType[_ <: MyData], Writer[_ <: MyData]]

val data: Map[MyDataType[_ <: MyData], Map[MyId, MyData]] 
// mapping from id -> data grouped by the type of data. 
// We've now lost the type safety since this is just a big bag.


data.foreach { case (type, map) => 
  writer.get(type).save(map) 
  // DOES NOT COMPILE SINCE IT CAN'T GUARANTEE WRITER AND 
  // MAP ARE OF SAME TYPE
}
```

I'd like to change this to something like

```
data.foreach { 
  case (type: MyDataType[T], map: Map[T#MyIdType, T]) forSome {
    type T <: MyData } => 
    // do save logic
    // COMPILER COMPLAINS - not found: type T 
}
```

but it doesn't look like I can use existential types in case statements. Note that I don't care about missing type safety at this point because my data is already grouped by type, so I just want a way to force the compiler to accept a type I through at it. Any suggestions? I also tried to parameterize a case statement but that was a no go:

```
    data.foreach {
      case [T <: MyData](type: MyDataType[T], map: Map[T#MyIdType, T]) => 
    // do save logic
    // COMPILER COMPLAINS - 
    // illegal start of simple pattern for the parameterization
}
```

Any ideas of how to do what I want?

Comment: Your `MyDataType` looks like a `Manifest`, an included feature of Scala which you should have a look to.

Comment: MyDataType is similar, though in reality it has methods. It's a type class I use.

Answer (score 0):

I am tempted to say, that even if there is a solution to your question, there's something which does not sound right in your design. On one hand, you use complex types which are nice for type safety and inference at *compile time*. On the other hand you use a map to store *runtime* information. So either, you simplify your traits and forget about type-saftey, or you forget about storing types in maps at runtime.

For example, if you want to associate a writer to a particular MyData subclass, you could use type classes, which are flexible and resolved at compile-time.

Comment: In my application, the particular instance of MyDataType is actually a type class.

Answer (score 0):

Does this is what you want?

```
trait MyData

trait MyId

trait Writer[T <: MyData] {
  def save(data: T)
}

var writers: Map[Manifest[_ <: MyData], Writer[MyData]] = Map.empty

var data: Map[MyId, (MyData, Manifest[_ <: MyData])] = Map.empty

data.foreach {
  case (id, (d, m)) =>
    writers.get(m).map(_.save(d)) // [1]
}

def addData[T <: MyData](id: MyId, d: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = {
  data += ((id, (d, m)))
}
// you don't need to give the m parameter, it is given by the compiler
addData(new MyId {}, new MyData {})
```

1. you surely want a better search logic here